# Identify a (post nuclear?) fallout story

Tags: identification-request

The plot is a bit hazy for me since I read this novel years ago but can someone tell me if they know this book? 
The plot:

- Bomb goes off in the UK.
- Building collapse and many people die.
- Society starts to break down
- The hero and his family own a shop and have hidden supplies which wasn't allowed.
- The hero saves girl from rogue gangs when going to collect water.
- They fall in love.
- Corrupt soldiers are introduced who take food and gun supplies and set up base in hills surrounding the city
- Heroes mum dies at the beginning but dad dies later on and so does brother or sister.
- A big revolution topples the army and freedom of the people lead to the formation of a new community of survivors.
- The new community builds churches and teaches kids etc.
- The mutated ground meant the food grown was deadly and I think a cow dies of being too skinny.
- Eventually the new community fails and people are dropping dead. They run out of food in the new reformed city and the hero and heroine decide to escape to look for some kind of utopia.
- They run into rogue gangs in other cities but barely survive.
- They find utopia in last chapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, after 5 days I found it due to some research.

The book is called [*Brother in the Land*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brother_in_the_Land) by Robert Swindells

[image: Cover]

I happened to stumble upon it while reading his other book *Stone Cold*.

The plot is actually similar, but not exactly as what I stated.

According to Wiki the plot goes:

> "The narrative begins on a hillside, where the protagonist, Danny Lodge, encounters a man in a radiation suit, who confiscates his bike and orders him to return to his home town, the fictional Skipley. Arriving there, Danny finds the town in ruins, and learns that his family's shop has collapsed, killing his mother. His brother Ben and their father have survived. Shortly after the war, Danny meets a girl named Kim.
>   The local Commissioner issues an order that the injured and infirm are to be taken out of the ruins and placed at the roadside so they can be taken to hospital: this turns out to be front for his plan to kill off those who will be a burden. Presently, the Commissioner's men come to the shop and arrest Mr Lodge. The lorry bearing Mr. Lodge explodes, killing everyone on board, and leaving Danny and Ben orphans.

The rest of the plot I said is accurate enough. Its a great read I suggest (if you haven't already) that you read it.